# I do not exist: A riley puzzle

Tags: riddle, wordplay, affix-riddle

My prefix is your Spanish,

My infix is radioactive,

My suffix is what I am not,

And I do not exist, like my imaginary friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefix

> SU (Your, in Spanish)

Infix:

> Ur (Uranium, a radioactive element - old notation )

Suffix

> REAL (Refers to the whole answer, somewhat negated (not))

Whole:

> SURREAL - Similar to UNREAL, which is a synonym for imaginary

Comment: Sheesh, that was fast. Turns out I can only accept an answer in 7 minutes..

Comment: But could you explain each answer like @cap?

Comment: More specifically, the "imaginary" part.

Answer (score 4):

*My prefix is your Spanish,*

> **SU** is Spanish for 'your'

*My infix is radioactive,*

> **UR** is ["an obsolete symbol for the element Uranium"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UR) which is radioactive

*My suffix is what I am not,*

> **REAL**, see next line

*And I do not exist, like my imaginary friend.*

> You are **SURREAL**

Comment: Chris got it first, cap... upvote though!